Cannot import type interfaces of AWS js sdk v3
I am using AWS pinpoint service with typescript. And I want to define return type for GetSegmentCommand's output. The docs says that it is exported as this:
export interface GetSegmentCommandOutput extends GetSegmentResponse, MetadataBearer

But when I try to use it in my project like this:
import { PinpointClient, GetSegmentCommand, GetSegmentCommandOutput } from '@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint';

typescript compiler gives off this error:
GetSegmentCommandOutput not found in '@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint'
What could be the reason for it.? And if I am making any mistake, how can I do it correctly.?
Looked at the docs of typescript.
Confirmed within node_modules package of @aws-sdk/client-pinpoint to verify that they actually export the interface.

Just tried it without getting any errors. Do you get the error in your IDE or when you run the actual compile (tsc) on the command-line? If an interface can't be loaded, the error normally reads "TS2724: '"@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint"' has no exported member named 'GetSegmentCommandOutput'... "

I too tried it with creating a separate project and it works there. But I think it is something related to the es-lint that I am using. ES-lint is not recognising this export, and with my checks setup at the time of commit, eslint doesn't let it pass. I will spend some time on checking it.
